# Problem with how to implement distance conversion

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to make a basic distance conversion app, and my solution is to convert the user input to meters first before converting it to their desired unit. However, I don't know how to implement it. How would I go about that?

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var inputNumber = ""
@State private var inputUnit = 0
@State private var outputUnit = 1

let inputUnits = ["Meters", "Kilometers", "Feet", "Yard", "Miles"]
let outputUnits = ["Meters", "Kilometers", "Feet", "Yard", "Miles"]
var conversions: Double {
    //conversions computed here
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Enter measurement", text: $inputNumber)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)

                Picker("Your unit", selection: $inputUnit) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< inputUnits.count) {
                        Text("\(self.inputUnits[$0])")
                    }
                }
            }

            Section(header: Text("What unit would you like to convert to?")) {
                Picker("Convert to...", selection: $outputUnit) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< outputUnits.count) {
                        Text("\(self.outputUnits[$0])")
                    }
                }
            }

            Section {
                Text("\(meterToKM)")
            }
        }
    .navigationBarTitle("How Far?")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should look into the `Measurement` class in Swift for conversion

Answer (score 0):

You can do the conversion in a method, say `calculateConvertedValue` and invoke it in a button within your section and make changes to an `@State` property say `convertedValue` which then displays the final value in your `Text` View component. Here's an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var inputNumber = ""
    @State private var inputUnit = 0
    @State private var outputUnit = 1
    @State private var convertedValue = ""

    let inputUnits = ["Meters", "Kilometers", "Feet", "Yard", "Miles"]
    let outputUnits = ["Meters", "Kilometers", "Feet", "Yard", "Miles"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Enter measurement", text: $inputNumber)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)

                    Picker("Your unit", selection: $inputUnit) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< inputUnits.count) {
                            Text("\(self.inputUnits[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                }

                Section(header: Text("What unit would you like to convert to?")) {
                    Picker("Convert to...", selection: $outputUnit) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< outputUnits.count) {
                            Text("\(self.outputUnits[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                }
                Section {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.calculateConversion()
                    }) { Text("Convert") }
                    Text(convertedValue)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("How Far?")
        }
    }

    func calculateConvertedValue() {
        convertedValue = "New converted value."
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, sorry, I'm confused with constructing the method. How would I go about that?

Comment: What do you mean by "constructing the method"? My answer already has details about constructing a function for conversion. If you need help with conversion between different units of measurement you should probably ask it on [math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), StackOverflow only deals with problems related with programming.